# How to get last reminder or next reminder date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to getting the last reminder date and the next reminder date from the SQL Server.

I have a start date and interval time

```
startdate = '1-Jan-20'
interval = 3 (months)
```

I want to get the last reminder date and next reminder by the SQL function

I want output as

```
lastreminderdate = '1-apr-20'
nextreminderdate = '1-jul-20'
```

Please assist me in how to do this

Thanks

Comment: What are the data types of your columns?  SQL Server doesn't have an `interval` data type.  Also, what if the current date is the reminder date?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff

startdate is a date data type
and interval is int data type

Comment: NEVER use 2 digit years - learn from the mistakes of the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fun way to solve this uses recursive CTEs.  The CTE generates all the dates up to the first one following the current date.  Then the most recent two values are returned:

```
declare @startdate date = '2020-01-01';
declare @interval_months int = 3;

with cte as (
      select @startdate as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(month, @interval_months, dte)
      from cte
      where dte <= getdate()
     )
select top (2) dte
from cte
order by dte desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6d1953c879db9302d3ec8b2399fb67c1) is a db<>fiddle.

If these series require more than 100 iteration, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

I am suggesting this because it is a very "SQL"-y approach to the problem, and a nice introduction to recursive CTEs.  The more efficient methods would use a lot of date arithmetic (prone to error).  This is also pretty easy to modify for different time frames -- such support requires a `case` expression but isn't that complicated.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff,

It is a nice solution but what about future date
If startdate is a future date

ex `startdate='2020-06-01'`

then how to get the next reminder date in the same solution.

Comment: @LEARNINGSTUDENT You won't learn if you don't try. Replace your original starting date value with your future one and run the code to see what happens.

Comment: @LEARNINGSTUDENT . . . You can just replace `getdate()` with the "as of" date that you care about.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @startDate Date = dateadd(month, -1, CAST('01-Jan-2020' as Date))
declare @interval_months int = 3
Select dateadd(month, @interval_months, @startDate), dateadd(month, @interval_months*2, @startDate)
```

**Output**

```
lastreminderdate    nextreminderdate
-------------------------------------
2020-03-01           2020-06-01
```